# HTML 5 required validator triggers on all buttons on the form

Tags: asp.net, html, required

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" placeholder="Company Name" BorderColor="#C2C4CC" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="28px" Width="135px" title="Enter Company Name"  BackColor="#F9E3CB" Enabled="False" TabIndex="7" required></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the mark up for one of my textbox with the "required" attribute.

My question is, I have 3 buttons on my form, cancel, reset and submit button. 
the html5 required validator should only trigger when the submit button is clicked. 
however, it still triggers even if I press cancel and reset buttons.

How can I assign html 5 required validator on only one button?

here is my markups for my buttons:

**Cancel Button:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Cancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ClaimForm/btnCancel.gif" OnClick="btnFallBack_Click" Visible="False" ToolTip="Cancel" draggable="false" />
```

**Reset Button:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnClear" runat="server" OnClick = "OnConfirm" OnClientClick = "Confirm()" ImageUrl="~/Images/ClaimForm/Clear.jpg" draggable="false"/>
```

**Submit Button**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnNext" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ClaimForm/submitbutton.jpg" draggable="false" OnClick="btnNext_Click"/>
```

Comment: Add type="button" or type="reset" to cancel and reset button

Answer (score 1):

Add formnovalidate tag in each buttons html code.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Cancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ClaimForm/btnCancel.gif" OnClick="btnFallBack_Click" Visible="False" ToolTip="Cancel" draggable="false" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by assigning an onclick function to that button and adding:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

use a input button - where set the type as button and make it to run as server

ex:
// this will trigger the required for text boxes

//this button will not.