# Separate button triggers "Please fill out this field"

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am building a web app with C# and asp.net.  In the webpage, there is a header with a search bar and a body with a form.  When I enter something in the search bar, one of the form fields shows the pop-up, "Please fill out this field".

This field is required, but for the form which has a separate submit button. So what I'm saying is my search button and form are connected but they shouldn't be.

Edit:
Code behind for the search button:

```
    protected void btnOpenModalSearch(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //get information from database to populate the modal box with

        PopulateModalBoxGridView();

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Properties",
                \ "openModal();", true);
    }

    protected void PopulateModalBoxGridView() {
        if (dtSearch == null) return;

        //sort the search results in data table
        DataView dvSearch = dtSearch.DefaultView;
        dvSearch.Sort = SortOrder;
        gridSearchResults.DataSource = dvSearch;
        gridSearchResults.DataBind();
    }
```

Code behind for the separate form:

```
protected async void btnCreateNewAsset_Clicked(object objSender, EventArgs evntArgs) {
    //create a new asset
    //first check for duplicates
    if (IsDuplicateAsset()) { return; }

    Asset newAsset = new Asset {
        //creating asset
    };

    //post the asset to Team Dynamix
    var addAssetUri = new Uri(locationOrigin + webApiBasePath + addAssetPath);
    responseMsg = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(addAssetUri, newAsset);
    httpResponse = responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    if (!responseMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        Notification.Show(this, "Error.  Response content=" + httpResponse, Status.Error);
    }
    else {
        Notification.Show(this, "Successfully Created Asset.", Status.Success);
        assetDictionary.Add(serialNumber.Text, serialNumber.Text);
        ClearTextFields(frmIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, can you share the code behind your page to give everyone a better view of whats going on.

Comment: does the code for just the buttons work?

Comment: It's a start, the problem might not reside just within that block of code mind.

Comment: What is your default enter press action? is it triggering submit of form2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [HTML 5 required validator triggers on all buttons on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159772/html-5-required-validator-triggers-on-all-buttons-on-the-form)

To save you the trip, I needed to add `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"` to my button

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="BtnSearch" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" data-target="#myModal" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/search.svg" Text="Search" OnClick="btnOpenModalSearch"></asp:ImageButton>
```